# "The thing is, is that..."

Tags: etymology, phrases, verbs, dialects, repetition

This is a phrase I've heard many people use, and it sounds wrong to me; e.g.:

> The thing about that is, is that she might take it the wrong way.

It seems to treat "The thing [...] is"—the entire *phrase*—as the **subject** of the sentence. Of course, even if that were allowed, the comma placement would still be questionable.

I'm curious to know:

- Is there a name for this wording?
- Is it specific to a certain dialect?
- Is its etymology known?

Comment: [There is also a resumptive-that](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001120.html): "The thing is that, when you look at it in a certain way, that..."

Comment: Honestly, I can't recall every having read this.  Not totally sure about never having *heard* it, though.  Language (used) *is* weird.  Just sayin'...

Comment: I've also heard "... the reason being is that ..." which seems like a similar duplication.

Comment: A not uncommon variant phrasing in Texas English: "The thing about it is, is that..."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the linguistics literature, they're referred to as either "double *is*" constructions or "*thing is* constructions". Various papers have been published on the subject which you should find if you Google these terms.

In one possible analysis, what is happening is that there is effectively an element such as "what" which is implied:

> "(What) the thing is, is that I'm going to be late"
>
> "(What) my feeling was, is/was that..."

Note that although they're referred to as "double *is*" or "*thing is*" constructions, the construction doesn't necessarily involve either a double "is" (notice "...was, is..." is possible) or "thing" (notice the example with "My feeling").

I'm not aware of a claim that the phenomenon is restricted to a particular dialect.

Comment: Here is a [Language Log article](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001123.html) on the topic.

Comment: Very nice, exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for!

Comment: I was just about to ask this same question in a general sense, but this answer nails it. Kind of what I expected, actually. +1 and a badge for you.

Comment: Once in a while, there is a rare person who uses a [_triple_ is](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3452).

Comment: Must admit I hadn't noticed the triple is -- interesting!

Answer (score 3):

This is incorrect grammar. However, it looks like something which was spoken out loud: people can not delete or edit their previous utterances, so people often construct sentences verbally which are not strictly grammatical.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  Dan Tao is not asking whether this is formally acceptable in writing.

Comment: @kosmonaut: I would argue that "Incorrect grammar" is the answer to the question "Is there a name for this wording?"

Comment: @horatio: There are a lot of linguistic phenomena that aren't strictly "correct" in terms of formal, written English.  They have names, they are often systematic, and they have been studied.

Comment: Agreed: just because you might decide that a phenomenon is "incorrect" (which really just means either you don't like it or don't know how to analyse it-- so what...) doesn't mean that it happens "randomly" and not susceptible to formal study.

Comment: @ Neil: Nowhere did I say "randomly." Nor did I even intimate that it was inscrutable. I freely admit that I did not provide a full and carefully worded treatise on all potential aspects of the word formation, but please do leave your straw men at home.

Comment: @horatio: In fairness, you argued that "incorrect grammar" was a suitable answer to the question of what this phenomenon is called. I don't think it is outrageous to take this to mean that you don't believe it is a systematic process.

Comment: Let us try to keep in mind, though, that blackboard grammar is artificial (as is written language in general) -- especially in English, where many of our formalised rules were imposed by people who thought English should be more like Greek and Latin. Things like pauses and repetitions probably ought not to appear in formal writing, but dialogue (whether live or written) would be quite alien without them.

Comment: @kosmonaut: it *is* a suitable answer especially with the caveat I made about spoken utterances. I freely accept that it may be the wrong answer, but Neil is certainly continuing some old argument with the next person he saw. You'll note that your own language log link stipulates that some consider it as some form of production error.

Comment: @horatio: I am just saying that Neil Coffey's comment was not out of left field.

Comment: As @tchrist has said elsewhere, we are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers.

Answer (score 1):

It not only sounds wrong, it is wrong. And the introductory words are not a phrase, but a clause that already contains both subject and verb and so does not require a secondary, redundant verb.

"Double is" is not a sufficient name, since the usage may not include any form of the verb "is", such as "The problem being, is that ..."

It is correctly called a "double copula" (a copula being the linguistic term for a word used to link the subject of a sentence to a predicate).

According to the third edition of Fowler's Modern English Usage (as revised by Robert Burchfield), the double copula originated around 1971 in the United States and had spread to the United Kingdom by 1987.

Comment: I'm not sure *"Double is" is not a sufficient name* for this particular example, but it's certainly too localised for me to bother remembering for future reference. On the other hand, I positively *expect* to get a chance to mention [double copula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_copula) on some future question here.

Comment: Arguably 'What this is, is a complete mess' is a valid paraphrase of 'What we have here is a complete mess.'

Answer (score -1):

I came to this page after finding Andy Murray being quoted on the Guardian as saying, "What being a good team member **is is** performing the best in your sport." I think this is an interesting question; when people start a clause with a wh- word, it can be difficult to avoid the double copula, because another verb needs to be found quickly (i.e. What being a good team member **means**).

Comment: But the Andy Murray quote is a normal cleft (or do I mean pseudo-cleft - I can never remember which is which). The original example is grammatically different.