# The problem is is that

Tags: colloquialisms, sentence-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“The thing is, is that…”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13056/the-thing-is-is-that)

Does anyone know when or why people started saying things like

> The problem is is that...

or

> The thing is is that...

It's as if they are using *isthat* as a combined single word. Does the word *isthat* exist in any modern dictionary? I can't find it anywhere.