# What do you call the the effect that causes people to miss the "the the" in this title?

Tags: single-word-requests, articles

Ages ago someone told me that most readers will not spot a double-the in a sentence. Something about the way we process words apparently filters out the extraneous "the" but I don't know what that process is called. Does it have an explicit term? What is it?

Comment: Related: [**“The thing is, is that…”**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13056/the-thing-is-is-that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is referred to [here](http://impossiblebrainmatter.wordpress.com/2013/08/01/paris-in-the-spring-an-introduction-to-cognitive-psychology/) and numerous other places as "top-down vs. bottom-up" processing, and is a cognitive error rather than a visual one - that is, the illusion is caused by filtering of the material seen to match expectations as opposed to a true visual illusion, which exploits faulty visual processing.

The original illusion is stronger than it is in the title here because the phrase is broken across lines:

```
PARIS IN THE
 THE SPRING
```

On a quick glance, the "top-down" processing matches the sentence against similar phrases familiar to the reader, and results in a match to "PARIS IN THE SPRING", and the perception that this is what is there. In contrast, if the reader specifically reads each word separately -- "bottom-up" processing -- they look at one word at a time, and see

```
PARIS    IN    THE    THE    SPRING
```

thereby detecting the duplicate "THE".

Comment: Searching the internet for the term "top-down processing" found many examples similar to this phenomenon. Very interesting!

Comment: I had forgotten until this minute that the movie "Attack of The The Eye Creatures" has [exactly this same error in its title](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/mst3k/images/4/4e/0418.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20070119194706).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably reasonable to to say that it is a facet of [inattention blindness.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inattentional_blindness)

It's a factor of how our minds filter stimuli for consumption.

I don't know if there is a more specific term that applies.